# How to Conduct Stress/Load Testing for a Node.js Gateway with Requests from Different IP Addresses?

Tags: node.js, server, benchmarking, gateway, stress-testing

Learning and Implementing Gateways with Node.js

I am learning about gateways and working on their implementation using Node.js. One specific feature I am focusing on is rate limiting, which I intend to implement myself. This rate limiter utilizes IP addresses to keep track of the number of requests.

To ensure the functionality is correctly implemented, I need to conduct thorough testing. In particular, I am looking for a way to make `multiple requests with different IP addresses` to test the rate limiting locally.

Consider a simple (not accurate to what I intend to implement) rate limiter.

```js
const cash = {};
const limit = 50;
const rateLimiter = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!cash[req.ip]) cash[req.ip] = { count: 0, time: [] };
    
    if (cash[req.ip].count >= limit) {
        if (Date.now() - cash[req.ip].time[0] < 60000) {
            return res.send("Limit reached");
        } else {
            for (const t of cash[req.ip].time) {
                if (Date.now() - t > 60000) break;
                cash[req.ip].time.shift(); // Remove the oldest entry
                cash[req.ip].count--;
            }
        }
    }

    cash[req.ip].count++;
    cash[req.ip].time.push(Date.now());
    next();
};
```

**Manipulating IP Address in Axios or Node-Fetch for Custom Requests**

I want to run a script where I need to make custom requests to a server using Axios or Node-Fetch. I want to perform some experiments and need to manipulate the IP address that is being sent in the request object.

Here is a simplified version of my current code using Axios:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const http = require("http");

function getRandomPrivateIP() {
    const octet3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const octet4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    return `192.168.${octet3}.${octet4}`;
}

function createAxiosInstanceWithIP(ipAddress) {
    const agent = new http.Agent({
        localAddress: ipAddress,
    });

    return axios.create({ httpAgent: agent, httpsAgent: agent });
}

const url = "http://localhost:8080/gateway";
const numberOfRequests = 1000;

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++) {
    const customIPAddress = getRandomPrivateIP(); // Invoke the function
    const axiosInstance = createAxiosInstanceWithIP(customIPAddress);

    axiosInstance
        .get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            // Handle the response
            console.log(`Request ${i + 1} successful`);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle errors
            console.error(`Request ${i + 1} failed: ${error.message}`);
        });
}
```

Above code throws error:

> Request 1000 failed: bind EINVAL 192.168.72.253

Is there a way to manipulate the IP address in the request object to have more control over the experiment I am trying to perform? I have explored Apache server and other dedicated VPS for benchmarking, but I would like to customize the IP address for my requests within the script.

Furthermore, if there are instances where I may be making mistakes or need to approach situations with a different mindset, let me know.

Comment: Remember, you have a *huge* number of localhost addresses in the form of `127.x.x.x` so you can make all kinds of traffic from there by using binding on your test requests. These addresses exist on most systems by default, but are local only. 192.168.x.x addresses are "real" in that you need an alias for that device, ARP mapping, and so on.

Comment: @tadman I did try addresses starting with 127 but it gives the same error `Request 10 failed: bind EINVAL 127.0.0.5`

Comment: You'll need to be sure you're binding on your `lo` or "loopback" interface. The regular one won't work.

Comment: @tadman Thanks man!, I found the solution and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it is as follows

The `localAddress` option in the `http.Agent` is used for binding the socket to a local interface's IP address, but it does not affect the outgoing IP address in the HTTP request. To achieve what I wanted, we need to use a custom DNS resolver to resolve the host to a specific IP.

Here is an updated version of the code:

```js
function createAxiosInstance(ipAddress) {
    const agent = new http.Agent({
        localAddress: ipAddress,
        lookup: (hostname, options, callback) => {
            callback(null, ipAddress, 4);
        },
    });

    return axios.create({ httpAgent: agent, httpsAgent: agent });
}
```

This code includes a custom DNS resolver function in the `lookup` option of the `http.Agent`, which resolves the hostname to the specified IP address.